# Solve the differential equation. $\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y = f(x),$ where $f(x) = 1,$ if $ 0 \leq x \leq 1;$ $ f(x) = 0, x > 1, y(0) = 0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation.

$\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y = f(x),$

where $f(x) = 1,$   if $ 0 \leq x \leq 1;$

$ f(x) = 0, x > 1, y(0) = 0.$

Find $f(\frac{3}{2}).$

I am confused whether to use the concept as follows:

An integrating factor is $\mathrm e^{\int 2 dx}.$
Then after multiplication, it makes the original equation exact. Is it okay? Please tell. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

The equation should be solved for $x\in[0,1]$ with initial condition $y(0)=0$.
The particular solution is $y=\frac12$.
 This gives 
$$y(x)=-\frac12\mathrm e^{-2x}+\frac12\quad \text{for}\;x\in[0,1].$$
Then one should compute $y(1)$ and use it as initial value for the equation on $(1,\infty)$.
We have $y(1)=\frac12-\frac12\mathrm e^{-2}$. 
The equation is homogeneous on $(1,\infty)$, then
$$y(x)=y(1)\mathrm e^{-2(x-1)}\quad \text{for}\;x>1.$$
Thus $y(3/2)=\frac12\left(1-\mathrm e^{-2}\right)\mathrm e^{-1}=\frac{\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e^{-3}}{2}=\frac1{\mathrm e^2}\sinh(1)$.

Comment: It surprised me a little bit when I learned fairly late in my elementary DE class that you can handle discontinuous forcing without splitting up the problem into multiple IVPs as you did here. Of course this is also correct, but it involves a little bit more arithmetic than my approach. Still +1.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine; multiplying by the integrating factor and integrating, you get

$$e^{2x} y(x) - y(0) = \int_0^x 1_{[0,1]}(z) e^{2z} dz.$$

Here $1_A(z)$ is $1$ if $y \in A$ and zero otherwise. So in your case, with $x=3/2$ the integral only goes up to $1$, and so you have

$$e^3 y(3/2) - y(0) = \int_0^1 e^{2z} dz.$$